# MySQL SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Tags: laravel

I only have cartt file in the model, it doesn't write cartt anywhere, but I get such an error.

> [SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQmLT.png) Unknown column
> 'cart_product.cartt_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
> cart_product where cart_product.cartt_id in (4))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused. Can you press CMD/CTRL + Shift + F and search for `cartt` in your project? You should have a query using a 'where clause' somewhere in the project and referencing something called `cartt`.

And *please* follow some file naming conventions in your project. Your model names *have* to follow PascalCase since that's the way Laravel generates them.